# How to get resources files from .exe (compiled by C#)

Tags: java, c#, visual-studio

Right now I'm writing C# application that is copy of Java (Maven) application. Java app is using Velocity to parse templates from folder `src/main/resources`. Using this is fairly simple, i.e.:

```
VelocityEngine v = new VelocityEngine();
Template t = v.getTemplete("path_in_resources");
t.merge(...);
```

I tried to did the same in C# (VS Premium 2013). I've added folder named `Templates` and added there files (right click on folder > new Item > text file), but right now I do not know how to get path to those files (from exe). Parsing NVelocity looks like this:

```
NVelocity.App.Velocity.Evaluate(velocityContext, new StringWriter(...), "Template name", File.OpenText("here_should_be_path_to_velocity_template"));
```

FYI I'm using nuget and I'm building my app via VS (MsBuilder), I'm not using NAnt or other build tool ported from Java.